# How to permanently show the full path of file opened on Gedit?

Tags: gedit

Sometimes I have files with same name in different folders and I get confused which of them I'm using on Gedit, because I can't see its path.

How to have the full path visible always when working on files ?

[image]

Comment: Your gedit window doesn't look anything like this? http://imgur.com/5Wp5Lcd

Comment: I inserted a print screen @BrianZ

Comment: You may want to report this as a bug. This one was marked invalid, but it makes it clear that you should be seeing a path at the top of the window: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gedit/+bug/457126

Comment: I don't see a full path either using gedit 3.18.3 (Ubuntu 16.04)

Comment: Please [edit] this question to change `witch` to `which`.